# Sharepoint 2013 modal dialog trouble (master page)

Tags: custom-masterpage, modal-dialog

Help me please.
Something wrong with my own master page (edited Oslo.master). When Im trying to add user\permission my dlg window is empty (iframe content is absent). I can see Title only. But after changing master page to default - problem is solving. Everything works fine.

Tried to find an errors by looking at master page code, no results..

[image]

**Update**:

I've found one working window - it is "Shared with...". (pic from the Web)
[image]

Comment: Problem is actual for all dlg windows I think. Check permissions, file upload, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it occurs in every popup than check the CSS class called `"ms-dlgFrameContainer`". Because it is your own custom master page so it might be possible that you placed `display:none;` css in that class for some reason.

Comment: Hello, Hardik. No, I did not change this class CSS :(

Comment: is that problem occurs in every popup?

Comment: Yeap. Every modal.

Comment: Is it possible that I lost any placeholders or something? My first master page, not enough experience

Comment: search "s4-notdlg" class in your master page if you had applied that css for your place holder. if this class applied than nothing will be appeared written in that class in popup

Comment: I removed all s4-notdlg in code but it still doesn't work.. Thanx for the hint anyway.

Comment: Fantastic! Problem is solved!
It was wrong placing of "ms-dialogHidden" in my code.

Thanks to all